# How to get list of all subcategories which are set “Include in Navigation Menu” as no

Tags: category, navigation, menu

I have tried to get all sub categories which are not include in navigation menu but those are being active, of current category in list page.

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(10); //10 current category id
```

Even this category collection also return **only subcategories which are include in navigation menu**.

How to get category which isn't include in navigation menu?

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //only active categories
    ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 0) //only categories not included in menu
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', 10)//get only subcategories of the category with id 10
    ->addAttributeToSort('position')//sort by position
;

foreach ($collection as $category) {
    //do something with $category
}
```

Comment: It also doesn't return the category which isn't not showing in menu @marius

Comment: @DRAJI. hmmm...it should. Make sure your indexes are up to date.

Comment: Sorry this also "$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')" doesn't return those categories

Comment: @DRAJI. Then It might be something wrong with your category tree. Corrupted data maybe. Some values for `path` field might be wrong. Or parent ids may be wrong.